# WordPress: get_post_status takes a long time

Tags: php, wordpress

I get an array with about 20.000 entries. Each entry has a PostID,

I have to go through these posts and check if they are published or exist.

When I query the whole thing with get_post_status, it takes about 15 seconds. If I take out get_post_status, I am at about 1 second.

Is there a faster solution to look if the post exists, which is then more performant?

The whole thing runs in the frontend.

Or do I just have to live with the fact at this point that 20,000 times querying the post status just always takes something ?

Here is my code

```
    // $superUserLeads is the Array
    $bikeEach = 0;

    foreach($superUserLeads as $data){
        $leadid = $data["leadID"];
        $get_post_status = get_post_status( $leadid );
 
        $ifKeyExists_EK_WKDM_shop_mail_bike_not_sold_1 = array_key_exists("EK_WKDM_shop_mail_bike_not_sold_1", $data);
        if($ifKeyExists_EK_WKDM_shop_mail_bike_not_sold_1 == true){
            $shopMailSended = $data["EK_WKDM_shop_mail_bike_not_sold_1"];
            $shopMailSended = filter_var($shopMailSended, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);  
        }else{
            $shopMailSended = false;
        };

    
        
        if($shopMailSended == true && $get_post_status === "publish"){
            // Here an array is created, which is returned at the end.
          
            $bikeEach++;
        };
        
    };
```

---

### Edit sql query

@AaronJ had An Idea, but
nnfortunately, that doesn't make any difference in the end when it comes to time. But it does make a difference when it comes to memory usage

The Query Monitor plugin tells me with get_post_status
16.87s 250.112kB 10.5593S 23.443Q
with the SQl variant
16,48s 170.182kB 10,1352S 23.451Q

here is the code

```
        global $wpdb;
        $query = 'SELECT post_status FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' where id = ' . $leadid . " and post_status = 'publish' ";
        $results = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);   
        
        if (empty($results)) {
            echo "no result, post not existing: ".$leadid."<br>";
            $resultsStatus = null;
        }else{
            echo "Has an result:".$leadid. "<br>";
            $resultsStatus = $results[0]["post_status"];
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_post_status` gets a lot of (sometimes) unnecessary data and it will continue to be slow if it's used often. To make this faster you can write your own query to get the data you need directly. Something like this.

```
global $wpdb;
$query = 'SELECT post_status FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' where id = ' . $id 
    . " and post_status = 'published'";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);
```

If you decide it's still too slow then you can move on to querying in chunks of 100 to 1000 $ids at a time by building a query and using  `in (id1, id2, id3 ...)` Something like this.

```
function main() {
    $leadIDList = array();
    foreach($superUserLeads as $data){
        array_push($leadIDList, $data["leadID"]);

        if (count($leadIDList) >= 1000) {
            $publishedIDs = $this->getPublishedIDs($leadIDList);

            // do what you want here with the published IDs.
            $this->dealWithLeads($publishedIDs);

            // clear the list for the next query.
            $leadIDList = array();
        }
    }
    // include anything left over on the list.
    $publishedIDs = $this->getPublishedIDs($leadIDList);
    $this->dealWithLeads($publishedIDs);
}

function dealWithLeads($publishedIDs) {
    // do what you want here with the published IDs.
}

function getPublishedIDs($ids) {
    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT id, (case when post_status = 'publish' then 'yes' " .
        "else 'nope' end) as published FROM " . $wpdb->posts . ' where id in (' . 
        implode(', ', $ids)  . ")";

    $queryResults = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);

    $publishedIDs = array();
    foreach ($queryResults as $row) {
        $publishedIDs[row['id']] = row['published'];
    }

    return $publishedIDs;
}
```

Comment: Hi @AaronJ, if i use this i get this error  SELECT DISTINCT status FROM wp_wkdm_posts where id = 23896 and post_status = 'published' . Also had to Add "global $wpdb;"

Comment: I updated the answer. Hopefully it works for you now.

Comment: You should _not_ fetch each record individually! Use `IN()` in SQL to fetch all records at once, that will speed up the whole process dramatically...

Comment: @AaronJ Thank you. Doesn't make a difference in time in the end unfortunately, only in memory usage. See my edited question with the code.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Could you show me what you mean using the SQl code. Unfortunately I am not familiar with SQL. I have edited my question with the SQL variant.

Comment: I've included the chunked example which minimizes the number of queries to the database.